# Pandas dataframe error: matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bokeh

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = 'd:\\a\\pandas\\test.xlsx'
data = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = data.parse('Link')
df2 = df1[['dataFor', 'total']]
df2
```

returns:

[image]

```
 print (type(df2))
```

tells me

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
```

trying

```
df2.plot(kind='line')
```

returns

```
matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xe4241d0
```

Could it be the environment?

```
Jupyter notebook > Help > About

The version of the notebook server is 4.2.3 and is running on:
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC    v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Where is the fault? Is matplotlib still the standard or should beginners go for Bokeh or for both?

Comment: This is all fine and works as expected. What exactly is the problem? What would you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: I get matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xe4241d0 message and no graphic shows up in the jupyter notebook.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend bokeh, unless you already know that you will only produce webgraphics.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In case you want to see the plot inline, use

```
%matplotlib inline
```

in the header (before the imports).

If you want to show the graphic in a window, add the line

```
plt.show()
```

at the end (make sure you have imported `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in the header).

Comment: missed plt.show() ... note to myself never post on friday late afternoon...

Comment: for anyone else looking for why [missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno) library is not displaying plots in a jupyter, use `%matplotlib inline` in single cell. (figured it out thanks to this answer)

Comment: %matplotlib inline place before the res.plot() not before import in jupyter.

Answer (score 4):

```
## importing libraries
## notice to import %matplotlib inline to plot within notebook
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime


## making a DF like yours
df2 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['dataFor','total'])
df2['dataFor'] = [datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11),datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 12),datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 13),datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 14),datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 15),datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 16),datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 17)]
df2['total'] = [11,15,17,18,19,20,21]

## notice date are datetimes objects and not strings
df2.plot(kind='line')
```

output:

[image]

if one wants to improve graph layout:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(df2.dataFor, df2.total, linewidth=5)
plt.plot(df2.dataFor, df2.total, '*', markersize=20, color='red')
plt.xticks(fontsize=20, fontweight='bold',rotation=90)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Dates',fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Total Count',fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
plt.title('Counts per time',fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on performing the plot but I got it solved by running the import clause followed by %matplotlib. I think I'm using the latest version. I've tried the " %matplotlib inline " but for some reasons, it doesn't work on my end.